Dynamically-created cube with mouse follow script does not follow mouse
The goal of this script is that the object it's attached to should move with the mouse.
public sealed class FollowMouseComponent : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private InputHandler _inputHandler;
        private InputAction _touch;
        private InputAction _mouse;
        private static Plane _plane = new(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
        
        private Ray _ray;
        private RaycastHit _raycastHit;
        private bool _isDragging;
        public void EndDragging() => _isDragging = false;
        
        public Camera Camera { get; set; }

        private IEnumerator Start()
        {
            _inputHandler = FindObjectOfType<InputHandler>();
            Camera = Camera.main;
            
            while (!_inputHandler.Ready)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            _touch = _inputHandler.Control.Touch;
            _mouse = _inputHandler.Control.Mouse;
            _isDragging = true;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if(_isDragging)
            {
                HandleInput();
            } 
            else
            {
                Release();
            }
        }        

        private void HandleInput()
        {
            var mousePosition = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
            Debug.LogFormat("{0}: Mouse position: {1}", gameObject.name, mousePosition);
            _ray = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
            if (!_plane.Raycast(_ray, out float distance))
            {
                return;
            }
            gameObject.transform.position = _ray.GetPoint(distance);
            Debug.LogFormat("{0}: {1}", gameObject.name, gameObject.transform.position);
        }
        
        private void Release()
        {
            if (!CanRelease())
            {
                return;
            }
            Debug.LogFormat("Releasing");
            Destroy(this);
        }

        private bool CanRelease()
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Touch is pressed: {0}, Mouse is pressed: {1}", _touch.IsPressed(), _mouse.IsPressed());
            return !_touch.IsPressed() || !_mouse.IsPressed();
        }
    }

I have a cube in the scene with this script. This cube behaves as expected. However, if I create a cube using another script and assign this script to it as a component, the created cube does not follow the mouse.
Here's the code I use to spawn the cube:
var gameObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
gameObject.AddComponent<FollowMouseComponent>(); 

What could be the reason this script-created cube does not follow the mouse?

Just compare the two cubes in the inspector. Since the script does not use any condition  regarding the cube itself, you might have forgotten to assign a variable in the inspector, a component or added the script on the wrong hierarchy. You should include the script in question that creates the cube. From there you can see how it looks different from the one manuelly created. Once you have done that, you can refine the question on the how to fix that difference

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly, the only difference between them is the name. There are no other components attached. The creation of that one by script, looks like this:
var gameObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
gameObject.AddComponent<FollowMouseComponent>();


What do you see in the console from your debug logs? Do both game object names show up there?

HandleInput is called by Update. I can see both names of the gameobjects. The output looks like this:
InSceneCube: MousePosition: (538.00, 342.00)
InSceneCube: (13.67, 0.00, 12.61)
DynamicCube: MousePosition: (538.00, 342.00)
DynamicCube: (-3.67, 0.00, 412.61)

I have updated the script that is currently running.

I have tried switching from Update to FixedUpdate. This seems to fix the behaviour. But I don't understand why.

Your Release code is deleting the script fully, you might want to check that Delete is called correctly. If your goal is to really only drag the cube once. EndDragging is never called and neither is the _isDragging set to false therefore

@Zibelas that is true, the reason for this, I wanted to test the dragging before dealing with release. Release should remove that script from the gameObject.

The fact that your DynamicCube is some whole number of units away relative to your InSceneCube is suspicious. Where does this (-16, 0, 400) come from, is that offset consistent between runs? Where does DynamicCube appear in your hierarchy? When I test your script (with missing bits removed) it works for me.

Thank you @Paul. The offset is not uniform. I had the feeling from observation that it looked more like it was gravitating around a position. In some moments it would match the position of the mouse for a short time, but with slight changes in that position it looked like the position of the dynamic cube was multiplied by a factor of 30-40.
Regarding your question about hierarchy, both cubes were on the same level of hierarchy. But as mentioned in an earlier comment, after using FixedUpdate this "offset" disappeared.

To diagnose this problem, you should change it back to Update. If you don't resolve this issue here it could come back to bite you later. My suspicion is _ray.GetPoint(distance) is different for the two calls to HandleInput. You can verify that by adding another Debug.LogFormat of that value. If that value is different it implies that the Camera object position / rotation is different too. So I would Debug.LogFormat the camera position and rotation as well.

@Paul I will try your suggestion to diagnose it. Thank you!

I have tried switching from Update to FixedUpdate. This seems to fix the behaviour. But I don't understand why.

Let me know if you want to find out why

Hello @Paul,
I would like to know the reason.
